# SharePoint Search rest api query in specific folder for documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

My Requirements,

I need to search for the file and also files customized properties through rest API but inside a specific folder in SharePoint.

I have used:

```
https://domain.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Title: Design' /GET
```

The above rest api returns the search result but it searches in the whole sharepoint document library. For searching the file properties and returing the file properties I have tried:

```
https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='Title: no'&selectproperties='Title,City,Phase,Job'
```

But the response from the above query is it returns only the Title but not the all other customized prroperties of the files

How can I achieve my requirements through rest API of SharePoint?

Answer (score 3):

To search in the specific folder you can specifying full folder path with `site:` managed property. Like this:

```
http://{site url}/_api/search/query?querytext='title:{query_text}+site:"{absolute path to folder}"'
```

Example:

```
http://server1/_api/search/query?querytext='title:Document*+site:"http:%2f%server1%2fLibrary2%2fFolder3"'
```

> Cannot tell anything about your `selectproperties`, because everything
>   seams ok, with your query, and SharePoint should return them, if
>   everything is ok with your search schema. Maybe, try to remove empty spaces.

Check if everything is ok, with your search schema, especially managed properties. There should be auto generated managed properties like Title, also all these properties you want to select using `selectproperties` also should be configured as managed properties with option `Selectable`

Comment: Do I need to set any setting in the sharepoint for working with the selected properties or search ?

Comment: The above query is not working for me if i give querytext="no" means it searches the whole sharepoint document library but if i specify a property to search means it doesn't shows any result querytext="Title:no"

Comment: Check if everything is ok, with your search schema, especially managed properties. There should be auto generated managed properties like Title, also all these properties you want to select using `selectproperties` also should be configured as managed properties with option `Selectable`

Comment: I have metadata properties such as date,phase,job,area,city etc all are in single line text datatype when i use this property in search querytext it not showing the result what is the problem do i missed anything ?

Comment: Is properties Selectable and Querable checked for these managed properties. After any change in search schema full crawl is recommended.

Comment: where i can see the options for selectable and queriable for managed properties, I have looked the property settings also but not found these options ?

Comment: Iam new to sharepoint online what do you mean by After any change in search schema full crawl is recommended

Comment: Sorry for my misleading comment, I forgot what you have SharePoint Online environment. My comment is for on-prem. Let me check that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25095/discussion-between-manoj-and-ecm4d).